# Change toggle position when another function is triggered

Tags: jquery

I'm toggling two functions on a button click:

```
function title_scroll() {
    var s = $(window).scrollTop();
    var fixedTitle = $('#headTitle');
    fixedTitle.css('position', 'absolute');
    fixedTitle.css('top', s + 'px');
}

function title_fixed() {
    var s = $(window).scrollTop();
    var fixedTitle = $('#headTitle');
    fixedTitle.css('position', 'fixed');
    fixedTitle.css('top', '0px');
}

btn.toggle(title_scroll, title_fixed);
```

This works great, but I have a third event that when triggered makes the toggle "out of sync" if you know what I mean.

Ideally when this third event is triggered I'd also like to activate the toggle, this is the third event:

```
var hammertime = Hammer(wrap).on('tap', function (event) {
    if (!$(event.target).is(btn)) {
        $(this).removeClass('slideout');
    }
});
```

Comment: you can manually trigger the click event like `btn.click()` in the third event handler

Comment: FYI, this form of `toggle` was deprecated in jQuery 1.8, and removed in 1.9.

Comment: @Barmar what do we use instead?

Comment: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/beginner-function-toggle-deprecated-what-to-use-instead

Comment: @Bramar thanks, I am now using the clicktoggle function :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually trigger a click event in the third event handler like

```
var hammertime = Hammer(wrap).on('tap', function (event) {
    if (!$(event.target).is(btn)) {
        $(this).removeClass('slideout');
        btn.click()
    }
});
```